# Any suggestion for a better email subject?

Tags: email

My senior asked me to send her an email as soon as I got to the office and just before I leave the office so she can keep track on my hours.

Is there any good suggestions for email subjects for those emails?
I'm currently using "**Logged in**" and "**Logging off**". But I feel like those are not really nice.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"clocking in" and "clocking out" are often used in this sort of context. You could also ask your senior whether she has any preference.